# Какие параметры надо указать для h2 базы в xml файле?

Tags: java, spring

Прописываю следующие проперти, но идея ругается драйвер - пишет, что не может его загрузить.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.JDBC"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test"/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: А драйвер у вас есть?

Comment: как это узнать?

Comment: добавляете в pom.xml?

Comment: и еще - в какой момент "идея ругается"? при сборке, запуске...?

Comment: при запуске ругается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете для проекта систему сборки maven.
Для использования в maven сторонних библиотек (драйверов), необходимо их указать в зависимостях в файле pom в разделе:
 **<dependencies>ваши зависимости</dependencies>**.
Для конкретно БД H2DB, вам необходимо взять строки подключения зависимостей по ссылке: [org.h2.Driver](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc).
После того, как вы подключите зависимости, вам необходимо справа в IDEA выбрать кнопку Maven Projects, там кнопку Execute Maven Goal, в открывшемся окне ввести "clean package" (что будет означать очистить предыдущие сборки и пересобрать). После этого все зависимости установяться в Ваш локальный репозиторий (по умолчанию %userhome%.m2...). И проблемы с зависимостями разрешатся.

Comment: пробовал, та же фигня была

Comment: Как собираете проект, сам jar с драйвером подключен? Если maven или gradle [вот](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2), если стандартно, то скачайте и добавьте jar вручную оттуда же.

Comment: Maven использую.

Comment: Значит подключите зависимость, затем clean package и все должно заработать.

Comment: что значит clean package?

Comment: Обновил свой ответ